# how do people pick the letters for syllogistic logic problems?

Tags: logic, syllogism

I encountered the following argument while I was studying syllogistic logic from a book:

> All red cars kill papers, (premise)
>
> All cars that kill papers are beautiful, (premise)
>
> All red cars are beautiful. (conclusion)

Of course, the argument is valid. But when I tried to symbolize the argument, I couldn't do it completely because of the problem which I will mention. The answer (symbolization) of the argument that my book suggests is the folowing:

> all R is K, (premise)
>
> all K is B, (premise)
>
> all R is B. (conclusion)

Of course this is valid, too.

My problem is: Why do we use the capital "K" for both "kill papers" and "cars that kill papers"? Shouldn't we use different letters for each of these sentences? I have this problem with arguments involving "that" generally as seen above.

Comment: I made an edit. You may roll this back or continue editing as you are probably aware. Welcome to this SE.

Comment: @FrankHubeny Thank you Mr. Hubeny, your edit has made me happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do we use the capital "K" for both "kill papers" and "cars that
>   kill papers"?

"[K]ill papers" is actually shorthand for "cars that kill papers". The statement is saying that all members of one set are also members of a second set; so the content of the second set must be defined.

Comment: Ah, I understand clearly now. Again thanks for your answer.